# iOS SecItemCopyMatchingを使用して手動インストールした証明書のデータを取得したい

Tags: swift, ios

以下のサイトを参考に作成したca.crt（オレオレ認証局の証明書）をiPhoneに手動でインストールし、
証明書信頼設定もONにしました。
設定->一般->VPNとデバイス管理の画面で構成プロファイルとしても表示されていることを確認しています。
参考サイト
https://rikuga.me/2017/12/24/oreore-ca-and-ssl-cert/

以下のようにSecItemCopyMatchingを実行しているのですが、
statusが-25300となり証明書のデータを取得することができておりません。
NSLogで出力した結果は以下となっておりました。

```
status: Optional(The specified item could not be found in the keychain.)

    let query = [
        kSecClass: kSecClassCertificate,
        kSecMatchIssuers: "Oreore CA",
        kSecReturnData: true
    ] as [CFString : Any] as CFDictionary
    
    var result:AnyObject?
    let status = SecItemCopyMatching(query, &result)
    let data = result as? Data
    NSLog("status: \(String(describing: errorDescription))")
```

アプリから手動でインストールした証明書のデータを取得したいのですが、
何か設定などが必要なのでしょうか？